# Python 3 - equating two different lists

Tags: python-3.x

If I have to ask my program to consider the below two lists the same:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,1,2]
M = [2,4,1,3,2,1]
```

How can I do that without converting them into sets.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to convert them into sets? In any case, another option would be to do `sorted(L) == sorted(M)`

Comment: Those lists are not the same. Sorting them usually makes a different list, because the order in the list is significant.

Answer (score -1):

L==M

You should try some things before posting a question

Edit: oh,  I see.  You need to construct a class and override it's `__eq__` method